# Azure .Net SDK - Method signatures that allow for {set;} for CloudStorageAccount

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am looking to see if anyone knows of any method signatures or method overloads that would allow me to remove my preexisting hard coded value for the credentials, 
`config.StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));`.

Allowing for a console application to prompt a user for Username and AccessToken which would then be able to be passed back to `CloudStorageAccount.

Answer (score 1):

*CloudStorageAccount.Parse* should work if you take the user's input and build a connection string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={args[0]};AccountKey={args[1]}";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in project settings, configuration settings can be accessed programmatically and dynamically updated.

[image]

You just need to declare a string variable that will contain the default endpoint protocol, your storage account name, and your storage access key and then use `CloudStorageAccount.Parse`  to create a `CloudStorageAccount`, just like @Stephen McDowell's code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stephen. I used your logic and altered it bit to fit my needs. I have included my code below, thank you again!

**UserUI()**

```
 public static List<string> UserUI()
    {
        List<string> accessCredentials = new List<string>();

        Console.WriteLine("Account Name: ");
        string accountName = Console.ReadLine();
        accessCredentials.Add(accountName);

        Console.WriteLine("Account Key: ");
        string accountKey = Console.ReadLine();
        accessCredentials.Add(accountKey);


        return accessCredentials;
    }
```

**ApplicationStartFromUserOptions()**

```
   public static string ApplicatonStartFromUserOptions(List<string> accessCredentials)
    {
        var connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accessCredentials[0]};AccountKey={accessCredentials[1]}";

        return connectionString;
    }
```

I then take the `connectionString` from `ApplicationStartFromUserOptions()` and pass that into my `GetConfig()` which handles most of the heavy work.

**GetConfig()**

```
 public static StartConfig GetConfig(string connectionString)
    {
        var config = new StartConfig();

        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        config.StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

        // Create the blob object.
        config.BlobClient = config.StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        config.ListContainerData = ListContainer(config);

        foreach (var item in config.ListContainerData.Item2)
        {
            config.Container = config.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(item);
            ShowSasTokenForContainer(config);

        }

        //Create the container if it does not exisit.
        config.Container.CreateIfNotExists();

        return config;
    }
```

Lastly I am calling this all within my `Main()` within my console application with `StartConfig config = GetConfig(ApplicatonStartFromUserOptions(UserUI()));`